# Python docx - Is it possible to add text in middle of a word document?

Tags: python, docx

I have an Excel and a Word files.

In Excel I have eg

```
Marc 
Henry 
Richard
```

In my word I have eg

```
TITLE
PARAPH 1    
Building has been done by : please insert name here
PARAPH 3
etc.
```

I managed to read Excel and to put good name for good word document. But Is there a way to insert names in the middle of my doc ?

At the end I'd like my word like

```
TITLE
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'

Building has been done by : NAME ADDED IN WORD FROM A PYTHON VARIABLE HERE

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: how do you want to insert names? is there any condition

Comment: There's no condition. I just want to insert text in the middle of a word document

Comment: there is no relation between input data and expected output in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the word documents, this sounds like a task that could be done well with the python-docx library. There's a helpful tutorial [here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html).

The first step is to either create a `Document()` or open one. If you want to open an existing one, just pass that as an argument like this: `Document('filename.docx')`. More on working with [documents](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html) here.

Then you can add a paragraph to that document using the `add_paragraph()` method on your `Document`. Pass as an argument to that method with the text you want to insert.

The python-docx [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) is extensive, and has some more good examples.

As for Excel, you'll find similar functionality in openpyxl, similarly well documented. [Here's a quick tutorial](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) on how to write Excel files (scroll down to "Creating and Saving Excel Documents").